# Merging two json (deep nested)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, stringify

I tried to merge two json both with `$.extend` and `$.merge` but no success. I also tried to attach it like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({"data" : [
    {term: request.term},
    jsontag
]}),
```

Here's my setup:

```
autocomplete: ({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var tags = $('#input-newsearch-2').val();
        var jsonfied = {
            tags: tags.replace(/,$/, "").split(",").map(function (tag) {
                return { tag: tag };
            })
        };
        var jsontag = JSON.stringify(jsonfied);
        var jsonterm = JSON.stringify({ term: request.term });
    //console.log(jsontag);
    //console.log(jsonterm);
    //var mergedObj = $.extend(jsontag, jsonterm); 
    //console.log(mergedObj);          
    $.ajax({
        url: "/source",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: [jsontag, jsonterm],
        success: function (data) {
            response(data);
        }
    });
},
});
```

Console:

```
{"tags":[{"tag":"value01"},{"tag":"value02"},{"tag":"value03"}]}  
{"term":"value04"}
```

I was hoping to get sth like:

```
[{"term":"value04"},{"tags":[{"tag":"value01"},{"tag":"value02"},{"tag":"value03"}]}]
```

Or even better:

```
{"data":[{"term":"value04"},{"tags":[{"tag":"value01"},{"tag":"value02"},{"tag":"value03"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this, and achieve what you desire.

```
const mergedJSON = {data: []};

mergedJSON.data.push(jsonterm);    
mergedJSON.data.push(jsontag);

console.log(JSON.stringify(mergedJSON));
```

And output will be

```
{"data":[{"term":"value04"},{"tags":[{"tag":"value01"},{"tag":"value02"},{"tag":"value03"}]}]}
```

Which fits your *even better* scenario. Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/shp3da5g/) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) js library for manipulating arrays, objects, ...

Comment: Interesting. But I don't really want to use another library just for that. Am I at least on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

So what seems to work is if I first merge the arrays and then JSON.stringify() it ... like ..

```
        var jsontag = { data };

        var jsonterm = {};
        jsonterm['terms'] = { term: request.term };

        console.log(jsontag);
        console.log(jsonterm);
        var mergedJSON = JSON.stringify($.extend(true, jsontag, jsonterm)); 
        console.log(mergedJSON);
```

JSON result:

```
{"data":{"tags":[{"tag":"value04"},{"tag":"value03"},{"tag":"value02"}]},"terms":{"term":"value01"}}
```