# php/mysqli - combined selecting/filtering database of two nested json objects

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, mysqli

I'm sending json via $.ajax to php/mysqli. The json has two objects (data & terms) where terms has always one nested object and data: none, one or multiple ... like this:

Searching for value01 sends back this json:

```
{"data":{"tags":[{"tag":"value01"},{"tag":"value02"},{"tag":"value03"}]},"terms":{"term":"value04"}}
```

...

How can I now filter my database by the values given in the objects considering the above situation and especially that $arr['data']['tags'][0]['tag'] can also be empty?

Comment: Unclear, what is the exact problem? You cannot create query? Query returns wrong values?

Comment: I could need some hints how to handle this since I'm fairly new to php. I guess I need to loop over the object data?! And some condition to exclude if empty?!

Comment: Be sure to sanitize the values going into the query, so that bad people can't do bad things.

Comment: What are the best methods for it?

Comment: @PhilippM In reference to your update: Generally speaking, never skimp on the security.  Always err on the side of safe.  Is my answer considered sufficient or helpful?  On SO, your question expects an accepted answer.  Please mark mine with a green tick or post your own specific answer and award it a green tick.  (if you do the latter, I hope I will at least earn an upvote for being helpful.)

Comment: Might I recommend that the json data be built differently to simplify processing?  The following would be a good minimal structure: `'{"tags":["value01","value02","value03"],"terms":["value04"]}'`  Your current json structure puts `data` and `terms` on the same level, but I think `tags` and `terms` should be on the same level (and `data` is no use).  Are you able to adjust how the string is produced?

Comment: Yes I could. Please see here how I created the json. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122479/merging-two-json-deep-nested . Feel free to add how you would change it to simplify the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data=file_get_contents("php://input");
//$data='{"data":{"tags":[{"tag":"value01"},{"tag":"value02"},{"tag":"value03"},{"tag":"value04"}]},"terms":{"term":"value05"}}';

$arr=json_decode($data,true);
$mysqli=new mysqli(...);  // do this appropriately
$query="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name LIKE '%".$mysqli->real_escape_string($arr['terms']['term'])."%'";
foreach($arr['data']['tags'] as $array){
    $tag=$array['tag'];
    $query.=" AND `name` LIKE '%".$mysqli->real_escape_string($tag)."%'";
}
$query.=" ORDER BY name;";
```

Comment: @PhilippM If my answer solves your question, please award it the green tick, otherwise let me know what isn't quite right for you.

Comment: Sweet! Echoing your sample works great ... but if I want to embed it in building the required json for the autocomplete ... I get nothing back in the response and subsequently no dropdown with suggestions. Please see my update above

Comment: @PhilippM  I don't think I follow.  Where is it breaking exactly?  What needs to be fixed?  I have to have some family time, I'll be back later.

Comment: After entering a value and the script runs I get a [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 10563ms] and also please see my edit above ... . Normally it takes about a second for the suggestions to show up (in an example with a single term I have running). I'm trying to do some more debugging .. Btw originally I was looking at this example https://www.wowww.nl/2014/02/01/jquery-autocomplete-tutorial-php-mysql/

Comment: @PhilippM That error may be due to a invalid json object.  We'll need to isolate what is working and what isn't.  Because your program is expecting a valid json object, let's serve all error/success messages back via a json object.  First, was your code working before my snippet was included?  Are you connecting to your database with $mysqli; that declaration is not included in your script (I'm just checking, it doesn't need to exist on your SO post)?  Create an else condition for `$mysqli->query()` that will push `mysqli->error()` into the json object.

Comment: Will there only be one `data` line served to my snippet?  If so, the foreach loop is not necessary.  If there can be more than one line, then your mysqli block will only serve the final query because the block is outside the loop.  Have you got all error reporting firing?  Do you have anymore clues?

Comment: Yes, only one line of 'data'. Sorry that I wasn't detailed enough. I updated it above. And yes, when searching for a single value (//if ($data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name LIKE '%$term%' OR code LIKE '%$term%'")) ) everything works as expected. Regarding more information ... I'll try to implement the ->error() and see if there are more clues ...

Comment: @PhilippM Oh no, I just saw your edit.  Did you give up on your goal?  What's happening?  What did you find in your debugging?

Comment: @PhilippM Was my answer at least helpful to you?  Either way, your question needs to move toward a resolution.  If you have created your own solution, please post it as an answer and award it the green tick so that future SO users can move directly to the best answer on the page.

Comment: Your answer was helpful in regards to splitting the query and looping over the subquery. Yet, since its based on a different json ... I couldn't use it. It would be helpful if you could change your answer based on my solution in regards to sanitize/securing the values going to the db. Or do I need to open another question for it?

Comment: @PhilippM added the escape function on the values as requested.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help on this